# Many rows in one cell - How to wrap it into one cell

Tags: mysql, excel

I use mySql and there is certains cells, when i've done my query, that contains more that one rows when exporting using export tool(csv) in workbench :

For example :

```
"Sara Jane",adam,"(450) 555-1452",satata@live.ca,"119, chemin du bourgouin",saint-citerou,qc,j8a8j3,Canada,1980-06-03,NULL,"7 jours ( arrivée le dimanche 13 août) - 290.00$ 
290",,"[2017-08-05 13:04:50] frais de 25$ par personne pré-montage donc 50$ à payer (total 650$)
```

the thing is, when i'm trying to "add data to column" in excel after, Excel does not consider the text qualifiers and skip the line, Which start another row and mess with my data. It also does that in suplime text.

Do you have any ideas ?

thank you!

Comment: Can you show us your csv (an extract suffices). With search and replace in Notepad++ or something you can correct your csv.

Comment: There you go.(above) That's 2 rows, but text qualifiers open in first and close in second but still have 2 rows when i want only one.

Answer (score 1):

A very simple way is to search and replace. I just used Notepad++.

- Find-regex: `(,"[^,]*)(\r\n)([^,"]*",)`
- Replace-text: `$1$3`

I remove the second group `(\r\n)` - the new line between quotes.

[image]
[image]